# check if job in Jenkins finished using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have this shell script that checks is a specific Jenkins job is running or not:

```
JOB_URL=http://jenkins.local/job/stevehhhbuild
JOB_STATUS_URL=${JOB_URL}/lastBuild/api/json

GREP_RETURN_CODE=0

# Start the build
curl $JOB_URL/build?delay=0sec

# Poll every 7seconds until the build is finished
while [ $GREP_RETURN_CODE -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 7
    # Grep will return 0 while the build is running:
    curl --silent $JOB_STATUS_URL | grep result\":null > /dev/null
    GREP_RETURN_CODE=$?
done

echo Build finished
```

I put this script inside a Jenkins shell step, and it does what it suppose to do which is:

poll every 7seconds until the build is finished- once build is finished I get an exit code 1 which fails my build.

Is there a way I can "avoid" that exit code?

meaning -

- If a build is in progress, a grep for result\":null will return 0.
- If a build is finished, a grep for result\":null will return 1 but I don't want it to fail my build I just want it to echo something on the log and the build will continue.

Comment: Can you not put an extra if with an exit statement at the end. So something like if [ "$?" == "1" ] then; exit 0;fi

Comment: I put an extra if, but it doesn't get there it gets exit 1 before and then build is failing @RamanSailopal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
So the solution was to add `||`  and after that the condition for exit code 1,

for small things that you want to happen when a shell command fails, you can use `||`  :

```
|| if [ "$?" == "1" ];then


JOB_URL=http://jenkins.local/job/stevehhhbuild
JOB_STATUS_URL=${JOB_URL}/lastBuild/api/json

GREP_RETURN_CODE=0

# Start the build
curl $JOB_URL/build?delay=0sec

# Poll every 7seconds until the build is finished
while [ $GREP_RETURN_CODE -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 7
    # Grep will return 0 while the build is running:
    curl --silent $JOB_STATUS_URL | grep result\":null > /dev/null || if [ "$?" == "1" ];then
    GREP_RETURN_CODE=$?
done

echo Build finished
```

Answer (score 0):

I have answered at https://serverfault.com/questions/309848/how-do-i-check-the-build-status-of-a-jenkins-build-from-the-command-line/980448#980448

```
JOB_URL=http://localhost:8080/view/TestTab/job/JobWait
JOB_STATUS_URL=${JOB_URL}/lastBuild/api/json

GREP_RETURN_CODE=0

# Start the build
curl --user "username:password" $JOB_URL/build?delay=0sec

# Poll every 10 second  until the build is finished
while [ $GREP_RETURN_CODE -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 10
    # Grep will return 0 while the build is running:
    curl --user "username:password" --silent $JOB_STATUS_URL | grep result\":null > /dev/null || if [ "$?" == "1" ]; then
       exit 0
    fi

    GREP_RETURN_CODE=$?
done
echo Build finished
```